# start C-x e editor in sh-mode

Tags: bash, emacs, zsh

emacs: 23.3.1, zsh: 4.3.17, gnome-terminal: 3.4.1.1

My default major mode is text-mode.

When invoking `C-x e` in gnome-terminal I would like to set emacs to use sh-mode because it's very likely the mode I would set manually anyways. How to do so?

Possible solution - 
Is there a way to create a template file for the `C-x e` cmd (to add a heading: `# -*- mode: sh -*-`)?

**Solution:**

```
;; open C-x e editor in sh-mode                                                                      
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\(^\\|/\\)zshec[^/]*$" . sh-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files opened with C-x e are always with the filename bash-fc-*. You can set a file association to match this filename:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("bash-fc-*" . sh-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

Comment: You probable mean `"bash-fc-.*"` - but note that this would also match a directory. To be more restrictive, you could try a regexp like `"\\(^\\|/\\)bash-fc-[^/]*$"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very handy -> zsh files are named `zshec*`.

Comment: @Paradiesstaub I was thrown off by the bash tag on the question

Comment: On my machine, they're named things like `bash-fc.MTxtzv`, so I use `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/bash-fc[.][^/]*\\'" . sh-mode))`